# Recognizing keydown() in JavaScript with Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to use JavaScript (inside PHP) to recognize keyDown events - specifically the arrow keys. I have looked through various threads on here, as well as other sources but have not been able to find a solution. My code looks like:

```
echo '<script>
  alert ("Hi");
  $(document).keydown = (function(e) {

  if (e.which == 37 || e.which == 38) {
    alert("It works!");
  }
  if (e.which == 39 || e.which == 40) {
    alert("It works, also!");
  }
  });
  </script>';
```

The first alert is just there so I know it is even recognizing the script, which it is. However, when I press the arrow keys - nothing happens.

Comment: You should ensure that [jQuery and the DOM are ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) before creating your `keydown` handler.

Comment: Also, this statement: `e.which == 37 || 38` is _always true_ as either "`e.which` _is_ `37`" OR "`38`" - and `38` is _always_ true as its a number that is non-zero. You should consider a `switch` statement for this, but otherwise, you need two checks `if(e.which == 37 || e.which == 38)`

Comment: `$(document).keydown` is not jQuery.... hence why it is not working.

Comment: @somethinghere - Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
echo '<script>
  alert ("Hi");
  $( document ).on( "keydown", function ( e ) {

    if ( e.which == 37 || e.which == 38 ) {
        alert( "It works!" );
    }
    if ( e.which == 39 || e.which == 40 ) {
        alert( "It works, also!" );
    }
} );
</script>';
```

the code which you used will just add a method on the object which is returned by jquery and is not actually adding the listener :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not add event handlers with

```
$(document).keydown = ...
```

in jQuery.

It is either

```
$(document).keydown( function (){} );
```

or

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (){} );
```

Comment: Or `document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){})` and ignore jquery all together :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this little [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cchcLuz8/2/):

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
        case 38:
            alert("Go left or up!");
            break;
        case 39:
        case 40:
            alert("Go right or down!");
            break;
    }
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: `$(document).ready` is not needed, when you add a listener on the document

Comment: This works perfectly! If I decide to use a switch statement, I will go this route. Thank you.

Comment: You gain in clarity imho but that's an open debate.